# connect to azure devops repo - locally existing solution

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I have an existing visual studio solution which was cloned from a git repo (in azure devops). I recently reinstalled windows and vidual studio 2019. The solution is still there in my computer. I just need to connect the same to the repository in devops.

I connected to the azure devops account using team explorer (after opening the solution in visual studio). The connection happened, but the solution files are closed and there is only option to  clone the repository (see screenshot)

[image]

If I click on "Git changes"/ "Git repository" , it takes me to the git menu which has only option to create or clone repository.

[image]

Even without the team explorer, the only git options that I can see are clone or create.

What am I doing wrong?
what is the correct way to connect exiting repo without cloning?

Answer (score 0):

In the toolbar try clicking Git --> Manage Remotes. I'm assuming these are blank due to reinstalling windows. Click add, name it origin and add the clone url from the relevant azure repo for both Fetch and Push.

This can also be done using git bash by CDing into the solution folder and using the following command

```
git remote add origin [repo-url]
```